# Sinch Video Calling ios app using ionic framework

Tags: javascript, ios, ionic-framework, sinch

I'm trying to build a video calling app using sinch and ionic framework. The video call works fineon my localhost browser, but when I deploy the app to my iphone it throwing an error 'Error: SinchClient can't be started with calling capability. Browser not supported.' I'm new to Sinch. Please help

Comment: can you please mark my answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

The reason its not working is that WebView/Safari does not have WebRTC to make it work in ionic you need to use the Native libraries and build a JS bridge, if I remember correct ionic is a ui framwork on top of cordova so its a cordova plugin that needs to be built.

Comment: Are there no existing Cordova plugins that help with this?